# nginx for older php version with multiples folders

Tags: nginx

i got some older php app that must run under php5.6. so i made this nginx configuration

```
  server {
  ...

    location ~* (folder1|folder2|folder3) {
      include php5.6-fpm.conf;
    }

    include php-fpm.conf;
  ...

  }
```

this is working, but folders may potentially grow, so it would be "ugly" conf.  let's say:

```
location ~* (folder1|folder2|folder3|folder4|folder5|folder6|folder7|folder8|folder9|folder10) {
```

is there a better well looking config out there that could do the same?

Answer (score -1):

The construction of your regular expression is very basic.

I would recommend you read up on the syntax and look at some examples to get an idea of how they work, as even a basic knowledge will allow you to construct some fairly comprehensive pattern matching formulas.

For example, your "ugly" conf above could use the following regex to match `/folder` followed by any number, containing any amount of digits:

```
location ~* /folder\d+ {
```

Comment: uhm...the folder names i used where just and example.  real folder names, are not numebered.  in fact, are companies names so i think your suggestion will not work.

Comment: I can only answer the question as you ask it